# Why does this function residue equal 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, complex-integration

$$
f(z) = \frac{e^{2z}}{(z-1/2)^{2013}} 
$$
Why does this residue equal 0?

If I expand Laurent series, the right side will have $\dfrac{a_{2013}}{(z-1/2)^{2013}}$
$$
+ \frac{a_{-2012}}{(z- 1/2)^{2012}}+\cdots \frac{a_{-1}}{(z-1/2)^{1}}+\cdots
$$
and the left side will be equal to 
$$
\frac{\sum\frac{(z-1/2)^{2n}}{(2n!)}}{a_0 + a_1(z-1/2)^1 + a_2(z-1/2)^2+\cdots}
$$
where a.-1 is the residue and is what we are looking for

where . indicate negative index

something about even and odd numbers but I can't seem to figure out the pattern

can someone please help me?

Comment: Even if you dont know latex, can you at least format this question better. What are all these `a`s floating around for; for instance `a.2012`, `a.2013` etc. I understand a0 is $a_0$

Comment: Please use http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, it is quite difficult to read what you have written.

Answer (score 2):

The residue isn't zero, though it is something very close to zero. Develop the actual series around $\;z=0.5\;$ :

$$2z=2\left(z-\frac12\right)+1\implies e^{2z}=\left(e^{z-\frac12}\right)^2\cdot e=e\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(z-\frac12\right)^n}{n!}\implies$$

$$\frac{e^{2z}}{\left(z-\frac12\right)^{2013}}=\frac e{\left(z-\frac12\right)^{2013}}\left(1+\left(z-\frac12\right)+\frac{\left(z-\frac12\right)^2}{2!}+\ldots+\frac{\left(z-\frac12\right)^{2012}}{2012!}+\ldots\right)\implies$$

$$\text{the residue is}\;\;\frac e{2012!}$$

Comment: The series has coefficient 2n/n! on the top by the way...

Comment: @MathMA No it doesn't: what we see above is the series around $\;z=0.5\;$ . Certainly, around $\;z=0\;$ , it would have different coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Timbuc was on the right track but neglected $2^n$. As was already shown, $2z=2(z-1/2)+1$ so we can write
$$
\frac{\exp[2(z-1/2)]e}{(z-1/2)^{2013}} = \frac{e}{(z-1/2)^{2013}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n(z-1/2)^n}{n!}
$$
Therefore, the $a_{-1}$ terms occur at $n=2012$ so the residue is
$$
a_{-1}=\frac{e2^{2012}}{2012!}\approx 9.05\times 10^{-5170}
$$